# Ionic InAppBrowser HTML5 Video Player Zoom Option Not Available

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a small app where I have used InAppBrowser (IONIC 6)

There are certain videos which will get played in the app but unfortunately the videos cannot be maximised to full screen. The zoom icon of HTML5 player gets visible but it is not clickable.

If I open the website which I am opening (through InAppBrowser) from google chrome, the zoom option of the videos works fine.

Here is my **home.page.ts**:

```html
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit{

  constructor(
     private iab: InAppBrowser
    ) {
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
      
    const browser = this.iab.create('https://example.com/tutorials/','_self',{location:'no',zoom:'no',toolbar:'no', allowInlineMediaPlayback : 'yes', clearcache: 'no', cleardata: 'no', clearsessioncache : 'no'}); 

  }
}
```

I have searched a lot, but could not find any solution to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic InAppBrowser has many issues with it. I am searching for this answer since the last 6 months but could not find one.

Comment: Yes there must be some way but still figuring it out.